# Show exchange disclaimer in new mail preview

Tags: windows-10, email, microsoft-office, exchange, rules

I'm trying to unify all company's signatures using exchange disclaimer rule, but users are upset because they can't see their signatures before sending the mail. So my question is can i show the disclaimer in the new mail windows.?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO. The signatures configured in mail flow rules are added server side(after the message is sent) and users can’t verify the signatures.

According to microsoft’s [document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/policy-and-compliance/mail-flow-rules/signatures?view=exchserver-2019#:%7E:text=Limitations%20of%20organization%20wide%20signatures).

Limitations of organization wide signatures

Exchange Server signatures can't fulfill the following scenarios:

•   Insert the signature directly under the latest email reply or forward.

•   Display server-side email signatures in users' Sent Items folders.

•   Skip lines which contain variables that couldn't be updated (for example, if the value wasn't provided for a user).

To gain these and other capabilities, use a third-party tool. Do an internet search for email signature software. A number of these providers are Microsoft Gold Partners and their software provides these capabilities.